# How to run a .sql file once I am already in the impala shell?

Tags: apache, hadoop, cloudera, impala

I am already in my required database 
Now I want to run the query from location

[quickstart.cloudera:21000] > -f /home/cloudera/impala-tpcds-kit/queries/q4.sql;
Query: -f /home/cloudera/impala-tpcds-kit/queries/q4.sql
Query submitted at: 2017-07-11 11:18:13 (Coordinator: http://quickstart.cloudera:25000)
ERROR: AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1:
-f /home/cloudera/impala-tpcds-kit/queries/q4.sql
^
Encountered: -
Expected: ALTER, COMPUTE, CREATE, DELETE, DESCRIBE, DROP, EXPLAIN, GRANT, INSERT, INVALIDATE, LOAD, REFRESH, REVOKE, SELECT, SET, SHOW, TRUNCATE, UPDATE, UPSERT, USE, VALUES, WITH

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done using "source"

```
$ impala-shell -i localhost
...
[localhost:21000] > source commands.sql;
```